# Selector command in tellraw command does not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is this a 1.9 thing, or is my selector in my `/tellraw` command not working?
Here is the code:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[",{selector:"@p"},"]"},{"text":" Woah, this is wierd.","color":"gold"}]
```

For me, in 1.9 (16w02a), the command is not working. Nothing will appear in chat.

However, when I take out the selector:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[ ]"},{"text":" Woah, this is wierd.","color":"gold"}]
```

It works fine.
Is the way I did the selector for @p wrong?

Comment: Pro tip: It's spelled *weird*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect; you had not closed the current object before opening a new one within the array (causing a syntax error due to an object being opened without a name).

> "text":"[", **{** selector

As of 1.9, JSON input must be strict, in that quotes must surround key names and string values. Your `selector` tag was missing quotation marks around the key.

Fixed command:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"["},{"selector":"@p"},"]",{"text":" Woah, this is wierd.","color":"gold"}]
```